# Why text set with .after( is not rendered as html?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

With fullcalendar v4.3.1 in Alpinejs 2 app I want to show some text near with myCustomButton, depending
on current states of vars. I do it like:

```
eventPositioned: function(view) {
    console.log('eventPositioned view::')
    console.log(view)

    // document.querySelector('.fc-myCustomButton-button').after(document.createTextNode( '<div class=\label\>test12</div>' ) );
    document.querySelector('.fc-myCustomButton-button').after('<div class="label">'+self.getFiltersCount()+'</div>');
}
```

On the form I see text html as text with data returned in self.getFiltersCount function :

getFiltersCount 9
But it is not rendered as html.
How can it be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a DOM element in `after()` instead.

Ref. [MDN after()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after)

```js
eventPositioned: function(view) {
  console.log('eventPositioned view::');
  console.log(view);
  document.querySelector('.fc-myCustomButton-button').nextElementSibling.remove();
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class","label");
  div.textContent = self.getFiltersCount();
  // document.querySelector('.fc-myCustomButton-button').after(document.createTextNode( '<div class=\label\>test12</div>' ) );
  document.querySelector('.fc-myCustomButton-button').after(div);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but if I click several times - then text is added several times. If there is a way to showtext only once ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo, I updated my answer. you can remove the ```nextElementSibling``` before you add a new one.